# BLE Device connection

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, desktop-application, bluegiga

Please has anyone used bglib or BleDriver.NET to connect to a BLE device? I need help in using any of these libraries.

The issue is I have a bluegiga bluetooth dongle and a bluetooth calliper. I want to get data from the calliper through an existing C# desktop application. The desktop application runs on Windows 8 and 8.1, but it is just a windows desktop application. I am able to use the libraries to open the dongle's port but I can not connect with the calliper.

Can someone throw some light into this for me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to the above problem. The caliper is designed in such a way that it cannot be used through a customers' bespoke application, thus requires its manufacturer's Bluetooth application to work.